# In Gingitsune episode 11, they mention something called Misogi, what is it?

Tags: culture, gingitsune

What is a Misogi? One of the characters mentioned that she thought it was only performed in the ocean or under a waterfall.

Comment: It's a type of Shinto ritual, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogi.

Comment: Also, given that the answer has essentially nothing to do with anime, I'm not sure if this is really anime-specific enough to belong here.

Comment: The religious concepts seem pretty integral to the series itself, but I agree that the subject of what I'm asking might not fit with the site after reading the wiki tag for [tag:culture]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about japanese culture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misogi is a Japanese mountain ascetic practice of ritual purification. This may be undertaken through [...] standing under waterfalls, or other methods. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogi)

This practice can also be seen in other Anime, like [Sailor Moon episode 105](http://sailormoon.wikia.com/wiki/Wanting_More_Power!_Mako-Chan%27s_Lost_Path).

Comment: I know that this answer was already given as a comment, but like this you can actually mark it as answered :)